# Space at the beginning of new lines - printf c

Tags: c

I'm writing a program in C that reverses text line-by-line(-L) and word-by-word(-W). The line by line functionality works fine, but when I use the word-by-word section of code, I get spaces at the beginning of all my new lines, the weird part being that the space takes the place of a string or character.

I thought it was a buffer problem originally, but flushing didn't seem to have any effect.

Should output:

```
line3
line2
line1
```

Outputs:

```
line3
 ine2
 ine1
```

Should output:

```
789 456 123 line3
789 456 123 line2
789 456 123 line1
```

Outputs:

```
789 456 123 line3
 456 123 line2
 456 123 line1
```

Here is my code:

```
char * getLine(char * line, int  * sizeString){
    char in;
    char * temp;       

    int i = 0;
    while((in = getchar()) != '\n' && in != EOF){
        if(i > *sizeString){
            temp = line;
            *sizeString *=10;
            line = (char *)malloc(*sizeString * sizeof(char));
            strncpy(line,temp,*sizeString);
            free(temp);
        }
        line[i++] = in;
    }
    line[i] = '\0';



    return line;
}

void reverseWords(char * line)
{
    char * token;
    const char s[1] = " ";
    char * wordArray[25] = {NULL};
    int wordCount = 0;
    //pulling the first substring out
    token= strtok(line, " ");

    /* walk through other tokens */
    while( token != NULL ) 
    {
      //printf( "%s ", token );
      wordArray[wordCount]=token;
      token = strtok(NULL, s);
      wordCount++;
    }
    //printf("\n");
    wordCount--;
    while(wordCount>=0)
    {
        printf("%s ", wordArray[wordCount]);
        wordCount--;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    int sizeString = 10;
        char * lines[1024] = {NULL};
        char ** linePtr;

        linePtr = lines;

        if (!strcmp(argv[1],"-W"))
        {
            while(!feof(stdin)) 
            {
                *linePtr = (char *)malloc(sizeString * sizeof(char));
                *linePtr =  getLine( *linePtr, &sizeString);
                *linePtr++;
            }

            linePtr--;
            while(linePtr>=lines)
            {
                reverseWords(*linePtr);
                //printf("%s\n",*linePtr);
                linePtr--;
            }

            return 0;

        }

        if (!strcmp(argv[1],"-L"))
        {

            while(!feof(stdin)) 
            {
                *linePtr = (char *)malloc(sizeString * sizeof(char));
                *linePtr =  getLine( *linePtr, &sizeString);
                *linePtr++;
            }

            linePtr--;
            while(linePtr>=lines)
            {
                printf("%s\n",*linePtr);
                linePtr--;
            }

            return 0;
        }

}
```

Comment: 1. `sizeof(char)` is `1`. 2. Don't cast the return value of `malloc()`.

Comment: you have many mistakes.

Comment: Removed "* sizeof(char)" and casts from the mallocs. Thx @CarlNorum

Comment: This is the code after 3 hours of mangling it while trying to figure out what the problem was, so I'm sure some of the mistakes are from that, but I'm also relatively new to C, so any help/tips are welcome :)

Comment: 3. `feof()` doesn't work like you think it does.

Comment: Your `getLine()` might not reserve sufficient space for the trailing `'\0'`.

Comment: If you define `char s[1] = " "`, `s` will not be null-terminated and you can't pass it as delimiter string to `strtok`. (You don't even need `s`, just use the null-terminated literal `" "` as in your first call to `strtok`.)

Comment: Your `reverseWords()` exhibits undefined behavior if a line contains more than 25 words.

Comment: strtok now uses the literal " ", none of the lines have more than 25 words so I didn't bother reallocating. And it is possible for getLine() to not reserve enough space for the trailing '\0', but its only possible if the line is a length that is a power of 10, so it shouldn't be affecting my examples that I showed above. Thx @JohnBollinger @M Oehm

Comment: `getchar()` returns an `int` not a `char`, so `char in;` should be `int in;`.

Comment: Do _not_ use `feof(stdin)`.  Use the return value from `getLine()` to determine when EOF occurs.